# What does a negative Thevenin-equivalent resistance mean?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

What is the physical meaning of negative value of ["Thevenin" resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem)?
Sometimes in the calculations, a negative value of Thevenin resistance appears.

Comment: You should include an example of negative Thevenin resistance in your question.

Comment: i do not have the problem now but will post it when i get but i think the physical meaning does not depend on the problem but the concept

Comment: As an example, a [tunnel diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode) has an operating region where its small-signal equivalent circuit is a Thevenin circuit with negative resistance. This operating region is called the "negative resistance region".

Comment: :) -------------

Comment: @ ThePhoton Tunnel diode - good example of nonlinear element that exhibits negative resistance. The slope of V to I is negative in that region

Comment: And the classical example is the [glow tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-regulator_tube).

Comment: @ThePhoton Neon lamp?

Comment: Wikipedia has a great article on this phenomenon:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance

Answer (score 1):

Negative resistance cannot physically occur in the case where the circuit is linear and contains only passive components (resistors, capacitors and inductors). But for active circuits - usually where amplifiers are applied - a virtual negative resistance can be realized.

The physical meaning of negative resistance is that power is *absorbed* by the circuit with zero phase shift - rather than *dissipated*.

Comment: Is "absorbed" really the word you want there? I'd say "generated" instead.

Comment: Generated is synonymous  with dissipated, both meaning power leaving the circuit. I do mean absorbed. In the sense that power is going into the circuit.

Comment: In that case, I find your answer isn't clear when it says "the circuit" does it mean the circuit that we're making a thevenin equivalent for, or does it mean the circuit that's attached to the circuit whe're making an equivalent circuit for?

Comment: @ThePhoton My answer is more general than the Thevinin equivalence. It applies to either Thevin resistance or just resistance.

Comment: I'm still not clear (based on the wording of your answer) on whether it's the resistor or the rest of the circuit that is absorbing or dissipating power.

Comment: @ThePhoton it's whatever within the circuit that serves to represent the (virtual) negative resistance.

Comment: I'm sorry but i was in an exam and the negative thevenin resistance appeared within the circuit - and the right answer was the negative thevenin resistance - and we study only i think linear circuits with the passive elements you mentioned , first course in electric circuits

Comment: @MohamedOsama sorry for the long delay, but someone just pinged me with a vote up on this. Imagine a component in a circuit that neither stores nor dissipates energy, but rather inserts energy proportional to the current that runs through it. Such an element could be modeled as having negative impedance.

Comment: but are n't we modelling the energy sources already with thevenin voltages ? plus in the transient analysis in the text book there is a topic called unbounded response meaning the exponential is positive but what is that in real life? @docscience

Comment: @MohamedOsama I'm not saying the negative resistance is a simple energy source; it's rather a 'dependent' energy source. Dependent on the current or voltage applied across the element. Since the resistance comes with a negative sign it will tend to reverse the direction of the dynamic response. So if the response in the circuit was initially converging, adding the negative resistance will likely lead to a diverging response. And on the contrary could help stabilize a feedback loop. Negative feedback leads to stable loops.